# How to re-render all page with Redux on React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I'm using a component to translate texts on the screen.

Here is my T Class

```
//Redux store located in app.js
import { store } from "app.js";

export default class T {
  /**
   * finds the variable in store and returns the translation if exists.
   * @param {String} key
   */
  static _(key) {

    const state = store.getState();
    const translations = state.get("global").get("translations");

    if (translations[key]) {
      return translations[key];
    }

    return `*${key}*`;
  }
}
```

I'm using this class like this

```
import T from 'libraries/T';
import React from 'react';

export default MyClass extends React.Component {
    render(){
        return (<div>Here we write translation of name : {T._('name')}</div>)
    }
}
```

My problem starts here, User can change the language by using the dropdown located in Header. And when user changes the drop down, I'm updating language date in store.
But page doesn't render new values. When I go to an other page new language values are visible.

But I want to re-render page in saga or in reducer. Is this possible?

Comment: generally with translations, you're going to want to have a "language" flag in store, and then have your components query ```Translate``` library with the ```language``` flag - this way, language change will get react re-render areas where text needs to be updated

Comment: @Varinder can you please show me an example? I'm not sure if I understand you well.

Comment: It's a bit tricky for me to write up a solution tailored to this scenario, however [this article](https://medium.com/@ryandrewjohnson/adding-multi-language-support-to-your-react-redux-app-cf6e64250050) goes into details around how you'd generally want to handle translations with react and redux

Answer (score 3):

From what I'm seeing, you're accessing the store directly from within the component, and it can't detect any change of state because it hasn't subscribed to the Redux store, I recommend you use `React Redux`. ([github](https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux), with repository and documentation)

With `React Redux`, you would use the `connect` API to wrap your component, subscribing it to any change of the Redux store, then extract the desired state from the store and trigger a render of the component passing that state as props. Extracting the desired state is done using the `mapStateToProps` function ([documentation](https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux/blob/master/docs/api.md#connectmapstatetoprops-mapdispatchtoprops-mergeprops-options)).

I recommend reading, understanding and using `React Redux` because it has a relative simple API and yet very powerful and useful.

Furthermore, in your code, you could use `connect` in your `MyClass` component, extracting the desired state with the `mapStateToProps` passed to the `connect` and passing that state as props. That way you probably won't need the `T` class, you would achieve the same task with the `mapStateToProps` function (which will have the same logic contained in the `_(key)` method).

Comment: Thank you for your response. But I'm using T every where in Code, In components, In helpers and in library classes that doesn't use redux.

So, mapStateToProps is a solution that I use in my components, but not a solution for this problem.

Simply, If I can update my screen manually, It will delete all my pains.

Comment: That's correct, the method _ from class T implements a pattern in Redux called Selector, in which you create a method which receives the global state as argument and extract the desired state. That way you centralize the logic and reuse it where it's necessary, you can use it in the `mapStateToProps` of many connected components. In your example, you just need to add a `state` parameter to the `_` method.

Answer (score 1):

@fobus, if you try to use `setState` for updating the state whenever you call `T` the page will be render automatically.

You can use a function(ex. `dropDownChange`) for updating the state whenever the user select a new language.

Can you test something like the following code:

```
import T from 'libraries/T';
import React from 'react';

export default class extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {translationDate: {}};
    this.dropDownChange = this.dropDownChange.bind(this);
  }

  dropDownChange(name) {
    const data = T._(name);
    this.setState({translationDate: data});
  }

  render() {
    return (<div>Here we write translation of name : {this.state.translationDate}</div>)
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response but this solution is not redux style :(